# How can we find missing character of alphabet(a-z or A to Z) using java8?

Tags: java, java-8

I have one problem statement where I need to find missing char in given string, I tried couple of operation with filter and distinct of stream Api. But couldn't get desired output.

String input ="abc";

Expected output= "defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" [char from d to z ]

Comment: Create a `Set` (of the alphabet) and subtract the origin input's charactes from it

Comment: yes @MadProgrammer i can have two Sets one with a to z and another with input string and then i can do intersection set1.removeAll(set2) all missing values will be in set1. But if want it to be done using stream or others java8 features how can I, any idea?

Comment: Why?!  Any way, about the only way I can think of doing it would be to filter the alphabet, but then for each element in the alphabet, you'd have to do some kind of "contains" workflow, so I doubt you'd get much improvement - just saying

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner:

```
String output = IntStream.rangeClosed('a', 'z')
  .filter(c -> input.indexOf(c) == -1)
  .mapToObj(Character::toString)
  .collect(joining());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very naïve way of achieving this, using two loops. Could be much more efficient and elegant. But it works

```
   public class Replace {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            String input = "az";
            String[] myArray = input.split("");
            
            String compare = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            String[] myCompare = compare.split("");
            
            String output = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            
            for (int i = 0; i < myCompare.length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++)
                {
                    
                    if(myCompare[i].equals(myArray[j]))
                    {
                          output = output.replace(myArray[j], "");
                    }
           
                }
            }
            
            System.out.println(output); 
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: add the `break` within the `if` condition, because a character can't match with two different alphabets.

Comment: @Jesse , Muhammad Khuzaima Umair  Is there any way we can achieve it using java8 features?

Comment: What do you mean by java8 features? This will work in Java 8?

Answer (score 0):

Build a list of individual `String` characters (note, only using lower case)

```
Set<String> alphabet = new HashSet<String>();
for (int index = 0; index < 26; index++) {
    alphabet.add(Character.toString('a' + index));
}
```

*(you could probably just use `char`, but I'm kind can't be bothered working that out)*

Or if you don't want to use a loop...

```
Set<String> alphabet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("")));
```

or...

```
Set<String> alphabet = IntStream
        .range(0, 26)
        .mapToObj(v -> Character.toString((char)('a' + v)))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Get some input...

```
String input = "abc".toLowerCase();
// Yes, I know it's already lower case, but just
// in case you're getting your input from the user
// or some other variable
```

Filter out all matching elements...

```
List<String> result = alphabet
        .stream()
        .filter( x -> !input.contains(x))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

which results in...

```
[d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z]
```

Of, you could just do a set subtraction...

```
Set<String> match = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(input.toLowerCase().split("")));
alphabet.removeAll(match);
System.out.println(alphabet);
```

which also prints...

```
[d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z]
```

*nb: I'm `Stream` noob, so there might be a "better" way, but this is basically what I could come up with off the top of my head*